# Getting error when echoing out an array key outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Why is it that when I setup an array like this:

```
$plans[] = array(
  'provider'  => 'Boost Mobile',
  'plan'   => 'Unlimited Gigs',
   'url'  => 'https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/',
  'price'      => 50,
  'duration' => 'month',
}
```

I get an arror if I echo out a key like this:

```
echo $plans['plan'];
```

//Notice: Undefined index: plan

BUT
when I echo it out inside a foreach array it outputs the value?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: change `$plans[0]['plan'];` instead of `$plans['plan']`

Comment: Are you checking the answers or just ask question and walk away... @Fabian Amran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have define `$plan` with array so no need to take `[]` with `$plans` because it create multi dimentional array.

I have added both example with and without `[]`.

**Note**

```
$plans[] = array(); // It creates multi dimensional array
$plans = array(); // It creates simple array
```

**Code**

```
<?php

$plans[] = array(
  'provider'  => 'Boost Mobile',
  'plan'   => 'Unlimited Gigs',
   'url'  => 'https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/',
  'price'      => 50,
  'duration' => 'month');

print_r($plans);
echo $plans[0]['plan']; echo "\n\n";

$plans2 = array(
  'provider'  => 'Boost Mobile',
  'plan'   => 'Unlimited Gigs',
   'url'  => 'https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/',
  'price'      => 50,
  'duration' => 'month');

print_r($plans2);
echo $plans2['plan'];
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [provider] => Boost Mobile
            [plan] => Unlimited Gigs
            [url] => https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/
            [price] => 50
            [duration] => month
        )

)

Unlimited Gigs

Array
(
    [provider] => Boost Mobile
    [plan] => Unlimited Gigs
    [url] => https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/
    [price] => 50
    [duration] => month
)

Unlimited Gigs
```

**Check Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/834384)**

Comment: I see where the confusion came from. I didn't know that using brackets would create a multidimensional array. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Welcome... Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$plans` is a two-dimensional array. If you want to show `plan`, you need to use give the first dimension too, which is 0 in your case.

```
print_r($plans);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [provider] => Boost Mobile
            [plan] => Unlimited Gigs
            [url] => https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/
            [price] => 50
            [duration] => month
        )

)
```

And here is what `echo` would give you:

```
echo $plans[0]['plan'];
Unlimited Gigs
```

Click here for demo: **https://3v4l.org/Ytk79**

Answer (score 1):

You are actually just adding another element (which is, in this case, an array) to an existing array called $plans if you want to define an array $plans use this

```html
$plans = array(
  'provider'  => 'Boost Mobile',
  'plan'   => 'Unlimited Gigs',
   'url'  => 'https://www.boostmobile.com/#!/shop/plans/monthly-phone-plans/',
  'price'      => 50,
  'duration' => 'month',
}
```

So now you can retrieve the value of the key 'plan' from your $plans array with this line

```html
echo $plans['plan'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an array at $plans[0].

So your value is as follows.

```
  $plans[0]['plan'];
```

You can view full array by this

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($plans);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is `$plans[]` then you should do this

```
echo $plans[0]['plan'];
```

if it is `$plans` then it will be

```
echo $plans['plan'];
```